# Functional equation for the lambert w function?

Tags: functional-equations, lambert-w

I've been long with this question or trying to find something similar: Is there a functional equation of a reflection formula  for the Lambert W function? 
The Lambert W function  is the inverse function of $xe^x$.
 I haven't had success with series and integrals representations of this function.
I Try to use this expression $W(1+x)-W(1-x)$ but I did not get anywhere but seeing the graph does not seem like a very complicated function in the real plane at least.
Thanks for any progress

Comment: Have you tried working with the main definition of the Lambert function? To see if there's any symmetries? Note that it is multivalued though

Comment: try to use the original definition but it did not work, the most "useful" were the representations of the function in the form of series but it did not serve much.And about the second, at least it is not multivalued in all the reals but obviously it complicates a lot

Comment: There is the $W(x)+W(y)=W(xy(W(x)^{-1}+W(y)^{-1}))$ for $x,y>0$ which is some consolatory prize.

Comment: For example, find the solution of $$f(x+1)e^{f(x+1)}+f(x-1)e^{f(x-1)}=2x$$ Obviously this can be generalized on many manner.